# "I was thinking you might’ve missed my message"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, contractions

I have a question regarding the use of “might’ve”

Here I was thinking you missed my message.
vs

Here I was thinking you might’ve missed my message.

Would there have been any difference between using “here I was thinking you missed my message” vs “here I was thinking you might have missed my message”?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a little difference.

> ...I was thinking you *missed* my message

means that I had come to the conclusion that you had not gotten my message.

> ... I was thinking you *might have missed* my message

means I thought there was a possibility that you didn't get the message. I had not come to a conclusion.

In use, a speaker could say either phrase and might not make a hard distinction between the two ideas.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Should Ron have just said "I thought you missed my message" because Mary didn't initially respond?

Comment: Just for clarification, when you say ‘make a hard distinction’ do you mean both could mean the same thing in use?

Comment: @Kelso91 Yes, I think both could mean the same thing. Saying "was thinking" instead of "thought" and "might have missed" instead of "missed" could soften the tone of a statement, making it more tentative and  polite.

Comment: Got it. I appreciate your help. Just to be sure, if Ron had said “here I was thinking you missed my message” it would have come off a little rude but because Ron said “here I was thinking you ‘might’ve’ missed my message” it was more polite?

Comment: I wouldn't say the first one is quite rude, but the longer form is more polite. It sounds as if he wants to go out with her, so he's being extra nice.

Comment: ___“Wait, you were busy and were going to reply?”__ Does this message imply that Ron thought (or came to the conclusion) that Marie for sure missed the message and wasn’t going reply back because she only replied to the “scary movies”’comment?

Comment: I think Ron was nervous that she had intentionally ignored that part of the message, and is relieved that he may still have a chance at a date. At least, that is my guess.

Comment: Lastly. Ron knew she might be busy so could “wait, you were busy and were going to reply?” also imply Ron thought she possibly missed the message?

Comment: I think he's making an excuse for her not having answered, to keep his hopes up. But that's just a guess. We've gotten away from learning English to guessing what a writer meant based on a limited extract of something longer.